# How can I make my background colour for section 1/2 fill full screen?

Tags: css

How can I make my background colour for section 1/2 fill full screen?

http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/KWGWxz

```
<div id="sections">

        <div class="section one">



        <a href="#section two"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>



        </div>
        <div class="section two"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Make your container wider?

Comment: something like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KWGvxz ?

Comment: Looking for section 1/2 to fill whole screen of it's section. Orange represents section one.http://imgur.com/a/TuZkF

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/EYWzj

Comment: Your title is confusing by 1/2 I understand 50% or half ... but you mean the section 1 of 2 ?

Comment: Correct my bad about the title.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `VH` [length unit in CSS](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units), this stand for **Viewport Height** and there is also its counterpart `vw` which stands for **Viewport Width**.

A quick example with these would be:

CSS:

```
div {
     display:block;
     height: 50vh;
     background-color:#c00;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
This div will take up 50% height of the viewport that contains it</div>
```

Without seeing your CSS code in the question I can't give you an absolute answer but you will learn more by playing with your code yourself, with this knowledge. To make a `<div>` half the screen height simply set: `div { height: 50vh; }`.

*(you may have to set things like `min-height` as well and/or take into account other more-complex CSS flow things depending on your exact DOM structure)*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. I'm looking for section 1/2 to fill whole screen of it's section. Orange represents section one.http://imgur.com/a/EYWzj CSS is in codepen in post.